# Query to find exact count

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Below is my database tables I need to find exact count

`[Request]` Table

```
[RequestID] RequestName   RequestedOn
  1         XYZ            4/5/2014
  2         ABC            5/5/2014
  3         MNO            4/5/2014
```

`[Inspection]` Table

```
 InspectionID, [RequestID]
    1               1
    2               2
    3               3
```

[InspectionTrack] Table

```
TrackID InspectionID StatusCode FinishedOn
1          1          0         5/5/2014
2          1          2         6/5/2014
3          1          5        6/5/2014
4          2          0        5/5/2014
5          2          2        7/5/2014
6          2          5        7/5/2014
7          3          0        20/5/2014
```

I need the query like which are requests finished <=15 Days & >15 Days, where `Status` 5 is the finished status, here is my query, however it's returning wrong result (i.e.. Count should not cross 3, in my case it's giving double/wrong):

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, RequestedOn, 
            CASE 
            WHEN IT.[StatusCode]=5 
            THEN FinishedOn 
            ELSE GETDATE() 
            END
        ) <= 15 
    THEN COUNT(DISTINCT R.[RequestID]) 
    ELSE 0 
    END AS Passed, 
    CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, RequestedOn, 
            CASE 
            WHEN IT.[StatusCode]=5 
            THEN FinishedOn 
            ELSE GETDATE() 
            END
        ) > 15 
    THEN COUNT(DISTINCT R.[RequestID]) 
    ELSE 0 
    END AS Failed 
FROM 
    [Request] as R 
    INNER JOIN [Inspection] AS I 
        on  R.[RequestID]=I.[RequestID]
    INNER JOIN [InspectionTrack] AS IT 
        ON I.[InspectionID]=IT.[InspectionID]
GROUP BY 
    RequestedOn, 
    IT.[StatusCode], 
    FinishedOn
```

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: @Arion Passed  =2  Failed = 1

Comment: There's no record for request 3, so no `finishedon` either. Is that why it is considered failed?

Comment: @shree.pat18 edited my question, please check

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you trying to get the number of passed and failed requests or inspections? How do you reach the Passed = 2 and Failed = 1 result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
;WITH Results (PassFail) AS (
    SELECT CASE WHEN T.FinishedOn IS NULL THEN 0 WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, R.RequestedOn, T.FinishedOn) > 15 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS PASSFAIL
    FROM Request R
    LEFT JOIN Inspection I ON R.RequestID = I.RequestID
    LEFT JOIN InspectionTrack T ON I.InspectionID = T.InspectionID AND T.StatusCode = 5
)
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Results WHERE PassFail = 1) AS Passed, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Results WHERE PassFail = 0) AS Failed
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select sum(case when datediff(d,requestedon, finishedon) <= 15 then 1 else 0 end) 'Passed',
sum(case when datediff(d,requestedon, finishedon) > 15 or finishedon is null then 1 else 0 end) 'Failed'
from track t
right join inspection i on t.inspectionid = i.inspectionid
inner join request r on i.requestid = r.requestid
where isnull(t.statuscode,5) = 5
```

Assumption: If there is no record for a particular request in `track` table, it should be considered as failed.

Comment: Its giving result only for completed. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Er, does that mean it solved your problem or not? :P